# Can we enhance the favicon on a dark background?

Tags: discussion, bug, design

In Chrome on Max osx, at least, the favicon in the tab title kind of disappears when having a dark main background on the window. Can this be enhanced somehow?

[image: Top part of chrome window with code review tabs]

The image shows top part of window with two tabs on the main page of Code Review, and one tab from Stack Overflow. The icon from Stack Overflow is much more prominent, than the one from Code Review.

Can this be fixed somewhat easy?

Comment: Maybe make the inside of the magnifying glass white instead of transparent?

Comment: The CR Meta favicon has a similar (and possibly a bit more pronounced) problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/so1YO.png

Comment: Is this question still current?

Comment: @Mast oh, and how current it is, unbelievable ;-]

Answer (score 3):

This is still an issue on the main site, but the meta site is slightly better:

Code Review Meta:
[image]

Code Review Main site:
[image]

Comment: I know this is more of a comment than an answer, but hard to include images in comments in a good way! :-/

Answer (score 3):

It's even worse on Chrome 69 Incognito

[image]